# Use *.pdf’s in class library project (web)

Tags: c#, .net

I have some pdf's templates that are being used across many web applications. 
Can I add pdf's files to dll project?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly add them to the project, but I  don't think that's what you're asking.

Even if you add them to the project, they will not be embedded into the DLL. You could use some kind of hideous base64 encoding in a string, and deserialise it later, but that's just horrible.

Your best bet would be a shared directory or server, or just to submit to copying the PDF to each application directory manually.